# Is there a way to convert a large Batch Dataset into a numpy array? The Batch Dataset in question consists of 150,000 image tensors

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, image-processing

So I have used the `image_dataset_from_directory` function from the `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing` library to load my image data. It loaded it into a batch dataset. I want to convert this into a numpy array.

```
img_data = image_dataset_from_directory(
    r'D:/NLP_HUH_Dataset/archive/img_resized/',
    labels=None,
    label_mode="int",
    class_names=None,
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=1000,
    image_size=(256, 256),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=None,
    validation_split=None,
    subset=None,
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
    crop_to_aspect_ratio=False
)
```

But if I try converting it to a numpy array using `np.array(img_data)` it doesn't throw an error but instead it just creates a 0-dimensional array.
I have tried using a for loop to iterate through each tensor within `img_data`, converting each tensor to a numpy array, and then appending it to an array, but it takes too long and my kernel crashes before completing it. It crashes after around 10 minutes.

My system specifications are as follows-

- **Processor: ** Core i5-8300H
- **GPU: ** Nvidia 1050Ti
- **RAM: ** 16GB 2666MHz

Please suggest more efficient ways of converting a batch dataset into a numpy array.
Thank you in advance!

[0-dimensional Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbzEC.png)

[Batch Dataset is not subscriptable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMJUl.png)

Comment: Datasets contain the images and labels as ndarrays within them. Not sure the exact name, but with ImageDataGenerator they are `x` and `y` respectively.

Comment: Or maybe `classes` and `class_indices`

Comment: You do not have enough RAM for this, why are you trying to make this conversion?